# Parameter-passing in merge sort

Tags: java, merge, parameter-passing, mergesort

Good day! This program should sort the first n words in a file. Please help me pass the parameters when I call the method mergeSort_srt. When I run this, the console says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method mergeSort_srt(int[], int, int) in the type SortingAnalysis is not applicable for the arguments (String[], int, int)
```

I'm new to programming expecially in the Java language and I am so confused. Please help me. As much as I want to find the error on my own, I can't because I have little idea about this stuff and I need help from real people, not just by reading tutorials online. Thank you very much!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SortingAnalysis {

    public static void mergeSort_srt(int array[],int lo, int n){
        int low = lo;
        int high = n;
        if (low >= high) {
            return;
        }

        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        mergeSort_srt(array, low, middle);
        mergeSort_srt(array, middle + 1, high);
        int end_low = middle;
        int start_high = middle + 1;
        while ((lo <= end_low) && (start_high <= high)) {
            if (array[low] < array[start_high]) {
                low++;
            } else {
                int Temp = array[start_high];
                for (int k = start_high- 1; k >= low; k--) {
                    array[k+1] = array[k];
                }
                array[low] = Temp;
                low++;
                end_low++;
                start_high++;
            }
        }
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NO_OF_WORDS = 10000;
        try {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
            String[] words = new String[NO_OF_WORDS];

            int i = 0;
            while(file.hasNext() && i < NO_OF_WORDS) {
                words[i] = file.next();
                i++;
            }
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            mergeSort_srt(words, 0, words.length-1);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Sorted Words: ");
            for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(words[j]);
            }       
            System.out.print("Running time: " + (end - start) + "ms");

        }
        catch(SecurityException securityException) {
            System.err.println("You do not have proper privilege to access the files.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            System.err.println("Error accessing file");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Essentially what this error is saying is that you have a method, somewhere, called `quicksort`. The quicksort method takes as parameters an array of Strings (String[]), and two integers. But in your code, you have tried to call it with an object of type `SortingAnalysis`. Since the compiler cannot find a method called quicksort which takes this kind of object, it throws this error.

Though since I cannot find any calls to a method called `quicksort` in your code that you posted, I'll have to assume that either the code or the error message is out of date.

**EDIT due to OP code edit**:

Now that your code is accurate, it's quite obvious what the issue is. Your method `mergeSort_srt` is declared as so: `mergeSort_srt(int array[],int lo, int n)`. It's expecting an array of integers in the first parameter. In your main method, you call it like so: `mergeSort_srt(words, 0, words.length-1);`, where `words` is an array of *Strings*, not integers.

To fix this you'll need to update your mergeSort_srt method to:

1. take an array of Strings (String[]) as an input
2. update the sorting logic to work on Strings, as it is all written for integers or other numbers now.

Comment: Whoops I'm sorry, I just did copy-paste the error from another window. Thanks for recognizing! But that really is mergeSort_srt. My real problem is the passing of parameter.